# How to use getInputStream() on NSNetService in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, nsstream, nsnetservice

I’m trying to set up an `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` for a Bonjour connection on a `NSNetService`. The getInputStream method requires arguments of the type `UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?>`:

```
public func getInputStream(inputStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?>, outputStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSOutputStream?>) -> Bool
```

But when I do this the inputStream and the outputStream stay nil and succes is false:

```
    let inputStream:UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?> = nil
    let outputStream:UnsafeMutablePointer<NSOutputStream?> = nil

    var succes = service.getInputStream(inputStream, outputStream: outputStream)
```

Another problem is that I cannot approach it as an ‘NSInputStream’ because it of type ‘UnsafeMutablePointer,’. When I try this I get the following error:

`Error:(52, 13) value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<NSInputStream>>') has no member 'delegate'`

What is the right way to handle these mutable pointer types in swift? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pointers are `nil` because you did not allocate memory for them.
But the easier solution is to pass `NSIn/OutputStream?` variables as
inout-argument with `&`:

```
var inputStream : NSInputStream?
var outputStream : NSOutputStream?

let success = service.getInputStream(&inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
```